# GEE image transform is different when saving on GCS or reading as ee.Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, affine-transformation, geemap, google-cloud

I have accessed an image using GEE, and then saved it to GCS.
I observed an unexpected behavior when I'm trying to get the dimensions and transform of the image.

When I am trying to get the ee.Image object transform and dimensions, using:

```
img.getInfo() , 
#I get wrong transform and dimensions :
{'type': 'Image',
 'bands': [{'id': 'bio_1',
   'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'float'},
   'dimensions': [43200, 21600],
   'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
   'crs_transform': [0.008333333333333333,
    0,
    -180,
    0,
    -0.008333333333333333,
    90]}]}
```

However, if I save the image to GCS and then load it with gee.load_GeoTIFF, I get the correct transform and  dimensions:

```
img_geemap=geemap.load_GeoTOFF("gs://bucket/path/to/img.tif")
img_geemap.getInfo()

{'type': 'Image',
 'bands': [{'id': 'bio_1',
   'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'float'},
   'dimensions': [1160, 865],
   'crs': 'GEOGCS["WGS 84", \n  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", \n    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], \n    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], \n  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], \n  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], \n  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], \n  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], \n  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]',
   'crs_transform': [0.00026949458523585647,
    0,
    -78.79859975545301,
    0,
    -0.00026949458523585647,
    -0.01455270760273625]}]}
```

What is the reason for this difference? How can I access the right transform and dimensions without saving the image to GCS?

Comment: How was the image in the first case ingested into GEE? Can you share the asset?

Comment: @OliverLopez I can't share the asset but I have used the "ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage" function to do this

Comment: In the second block of code in your post you are loading a GeoTIFF, which is the one that was exported to cloud storage using `ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage`. From what I understand in your post, this one has the correct transform and dimensions. What I am asking for is the image that you refer to in your first block of code -- can you show how you are loading that image?